# CodeFluent returns null for a geography column

Tags: codefluent

My model contains the following entity:

```
<Address>
  <Id />   
  <SpatialLocation cfps:dataType="geography" typeName="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types"/>
</Address>
```

I have added the following partial class to the business layer:

```
public partial class Address
{
  // The geography spatial data type, geography, represents data in a round-earth coordinate system and has a default SRID value of 4326.
  private static readonly int SpatialReferenceIdentifier = 4326;

  public void SetPoint(double latitude, double longitude)
  {
    this.SpatialLocation = SqlGeography.Point(latitude, longitude, SpatialReferenceIdentifier);
  }

  public double Latitude
  {
    get
    {
      return this.SpatialLocation == null ? 0 : this.SpatialLocation.Lat.Value;
    }
  }

  public double Longitude
  {
    get
    {
      return this.SpatialLocation == null ? 0 : this.SpatialLocation.Long.Value;
    }
  }
}
```

I have added the Nuget package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types to the businesslayer project.

My console application contains the following code:

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

Address address = new Address();
address.SetPoint(40, 50);
address.Save();
Console.WriteLine("Latitude: {0}", address.Latitude.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Longitude: {0}", address.Longitude.ToString());

Address address2 = Address.LoadByEntityKey(address.EntityKey);
Console.WriteLine("Latitude: {0}", address2.Latitude.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Longitude: {0}", address2.Longitude.ToString());
```

The output of this console application is:
 40
 50
 0
 0

The SpatialLocation is not null in the database. However, the following line of code in the produced ReadRecord method returns null:

```
this._spatialLocation = ((Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography)(persistence.GetReaderValueObject(reader, "Address_SpatialLocation", default(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography), typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography), CodeFluent.Runtime.PersistenceSerializationMode.Default)));
```

I have added assemblyPaths to the project node but that does not solve the problem.

```
<cf:project assemblyPaths="..\LIB\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll" ...>
```

1. Why does CodeFluent not load the SpatialLocation in the ReadRecord method?
2. What does the assemblyPaths attribute do? Does CodeFluent need this? Why?
3. Do I need to call the LoadNativeAssemblies in my console application?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why does CodeFluent not load the SpatialLocation in the ReadRecord method?

You should check the first chance exception in the output window, because the `ReadRecord` method swallows exceptions. There are many reasons for not being able to read the value. In your case, I think this is a mismatch of version that you can fixed using a `bindingRedirect`:

```
<configuration> 
  <runtime> 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91"/>         
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" /> 
      </dependentAssembly> 
    </assemblyBinding> 
  </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

Don't hesitate to post the content of the output window, if you think there is another reason.

> 2. What does the assemblyPaths attribute do? Does CodeFluent need this? Why?

CodeFluent Entities resolves the typeName at build time. This is required to generate the right `ReadXXXValue`. Thus, if you are using a dotnet type which is not in the GAC, you need to add a reference to generate the right code.

> 3. Do I need to call the LoadNativeAssemblies in my console application?

You shouldn't not need to call the LoadNativeAssemblies in a console app. However, you must check the dll Microsoft.SqlServer.Types in the bin directory.

BTW, there was a blog post on http://blog.codefluententities.com but the site seems to be down. You can find an offline version of this post (maybe not up to date) on OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/w/s!AkYmf2ZXtwX4gfA27FKegjJgz5PB8g

Comment: The bindingRedirect solved the problem. I had to redirect to new version 14.0.0.0. It seems that CodeFluent does not need the assemblyPaths attribute in my project, because without this attribute my applications works fine too.